# fastify connect stylesheet ejs

Tags: node.js, typescript, server, fastify

How can I include static files in FASTIFY?

For example, in express I do this: 
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/static")));`

fastify:

```
fastify.register(require("@fastify/view"), {
    engine: {
        ejs: require("ejs"),
    },
    root: path.join(__dirname, "pages"),
});
```

I don't think that's in fastify. What do you recommend?
Maybe someone has faced this task, there is nothing in the documentation

```
declare namespace fastifyView {
  export interface FastifyViewOptions {
    engine: {
      ejs?: any;
      eta?: any;
      nunjucks?: any;
      pug?: any;
      handlebars?: any;
      mustache?: any;
      'art-template'?: any;
      twig?: any;
      liquid?: any;
      dot?: any;
    };
    templates?: string | string[];
    includeViewExtension?: boolean;
    options?: object;
    charset?: string;
    maxCache?: number;
    production?: boolean;
    defaultContext?: object;
    layout?: string;
    root?: string;
    viewExt?: string;
    propertyName?: string;
  }
```

Comment: you need to use this plugin https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon But it doesn't support EJS, does it?

Comment: Yeah. I got it all figured out. I was trying to look for examples of what I needed. But unfortunately it's not online. But I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I decided it this way:

```
fastify.register(require("@fastify/view"), {
    engine: {
      ejs: require("ejs"),
    },
    root: path.join(__dirname, "template"),
    viewExt: "html", // Sets the default extension to `.handlebars`,
    includeViewExtension: true,
  });


  fastify.register(require("@fastify/static"), {
    root: path.join(__dirname, "style"),
  });
  
  fastify.get("/", (req, reply) => {
    reply.view("index.html", { ws: "het" });
  });
```